# How to make a L-shape web frame with Flutter Go_Router?

Tags: flutter

I would like to make an inverted L-shape web frame with Go_Router package which looks like this:

[image]

I searched on the web but it doesn't seem to have much info on this.  I even tried ChatGPT, it says using Stack, Positioned and 2 ShellRoutes, but I am not sure if it is the right way.

Here is what I am doing with the left hand side vertical bar:

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        ScreenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        MenuSpacing = ScreenWidth * 0.01;
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Header(), // Header Image
                Container(  // Menu Bar
                  height: 50,
                  color: globals.MenuBarBackgroundColor,
                  child: Row(
                      children: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => context.go("/"),
                      child: Text("Home", style: globals.MenuBarStyle),
                    ),
                   //  several Text Buttons as Menu Bar Items
                  ]),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child:
                    child,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: "/",

          // path configurations
```

Comment: This is a lot of work. And this is like two questions. 1) Build the Shelroute page with L shape and 2) how to build the navigation with the shelroutes.... I looked up your recent questions and there you already asked how to build L shape. You cant expect from some one to make the whole work for you. 
And what you builded so far will not look like the L-shape you expecting. And I think your question is how to build the Routing with Shellroute? So all in all I dont get what your question is. building L shape? building routing with go_route? Update your question and I will try to answer you.

Comment: Thanks Orhan, my existing app already works with ShellRoute and go_route, only if there is a top fixed navigation bar but without the left vertical bar.  What I am asking is how to add a vertical bar under my existing navigation bar and on the left hand side of the body (pink box). Referring to the image above, the header, container, and child is working fine now.

Comment: Ok, I finally give up insisting an L shape frame, but import a vertical bar class in every page.  Although this is not my first thought, but I got the outcome I want.